# Is there any meaning behind this $E=mc^2$ "proof"?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, optics, action

The action $\mathcal{S}$ for a conservative system can be written: $\mathcal{S}=\mathcal{S_o}-Ht$ (because $\frac{\partial \mathcal{S}}{\partial t}=-H$). We also know that: $\frac{\partial \mathcal{S}}{\partial q}=p\Rightarrow \vec{\nabla}\mathcal{S}=\vec{p}$ which means that $\vec{p}$ is orthogonal to the surface where the action is constant. We can make the analogy between the wavefront/light ray and the action surface/momentum because of the eikonal equation.

If we push the analogy far enough, we can try to find a group and a phase velocity of these action surfaces.

The group velocity $v$ is the speed of the object: $v=\sqrt{\dfrac{2T}{m}}=\sqrt{\dfrac{2(H-V)}{m}}$
The phase velocity $u$ is the speed of the surface: $u=\dfrac{dl}{dt}$.

Now, to express $u$ with the energy: we see that $\mathcal{S_o}=\mathcal{S}+Ht$ furthemore, we consider that $\mathcal{S}=cst$ (because we are working with constant surfaces of the action). In this case, we have: $\vec{\nabla}\mathcal{S}=\vec{\nabla}\mathcal{S_o}$ and we know that: $\vec{\nabla}\mathcal{S_o}\cdot \vec{\mathrm{d}l}=\mathrm{d}\mathcal{S_o}\Rightarrow \mathrm{d}l=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\mathcal{S}_o}{|\vec{\nabla}\mathcal{S}_o|}=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\mathcal{S}_o}{p}$ and we can also say that $\mathrm{d}\mathcal{S}_o=H\mathrm{d}t\Rightarrow\mathrm{d}t=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\mathcal{S}_o}{H}$. And for the end: $\dfrac{p^2}{2m}+V=H\Rightarrow p=\sqrt{2m(H-V)}$

Back to the velocity: $u=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}l}{\mathrm{d}t}=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\mathcal{S}_o}{\sqrt{2m(H-V)}}\dfrac{H}{\mathrm{d}\mathcal{S}_0}$.

No we find that: $uv=\dfrac{H}{m}$ and in the vacuum, for an electromagnetic wave: $uv=c^2$. If we "accept" the analogy between optic and mechanics and equalize the two $uv$ we get $H=mc^2$.

So my question is as follows: is there any meaning behind this, knowing that relativity is not used or is it just a coincidence?

I think I've just forced the fate trying to obtain something using questionables links! On top of that $H$ represents the total energy not just the 'rest' energy...

Answer (score 0):

If you used the properties of an electromagnetic wave, I think that should've also used the fact that in vacuum an EM wave has no mass that is m=0.

So you are dividing by 0 at the beginning of your proof.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @garyp you can conclude anything out of an equation that is wrong. In order to answer if theres a meaning in the proof one has to test its plausability.  Its kinda silly to just answer No.